# Why is NGINX giving 504 gateway timeout error?

Tags: nginx, web, gunicorn, portforwarding

My `NGINX` conf is-

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site.com ;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000;

    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

I am running a Flask app on `Gunicorn` on `Port 8000`. When I try to access my site, I get a `504 Gateway Time-out` `nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)`.

In the `error.log` , it says-

```
 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client:myip server: site.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://0.0.0.0:8000/", host: "mysite.com"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some errors in your config.

- You cannot have one server who is listening on multiple ports.
- You should not write 0.0.0.0:8000, but try 127.0.0.1:8000 instead

Also I dont understand why you include proxy params, just delete that line.

Here is an example of what you could do.

```
server {
        server_name site.com www.site.com;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
        }
        listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.com/privkey.pem;
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
server {
        if ($host = www.site.com) {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
        if ($host = site.com) {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name site.com www.site.com;
        return 404;
}
```

Good Luck :-)

Comment: do I place this in nginx.conf or in sites-enabled/mysite ?? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have all my different domains in sites-avalible and then i have shortcuts to those files in sites-enabled.
`sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/site.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

Look at some of the tutorials on digitalocean. They are really good

Comment: When I do this, and try to visit https://example.com I get 504 gateway timeout. Even though the application is running on port 8000 and can be accessed by myip:8000.

Comment: do you have your DNS settings set up correct, and did you restart nginx?

Comment: Yes. It used to work perfectly till today, I don't know what happened.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! It was some issue with my firewall.Fixed it!

Answer (score -1):

Suggest to keep like below values, which could resolve the timeout issue.

```
proxy_connect_timeout   300;
proxy_send_timeout      300;
proxy_read_timeout      300;
```